# Scope of variables in lambda calculus / haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Given an expression like s := (λx, y, z.x y z) λx, y.x λy, z.z, is the scope of the bound variables

s := (λx, y, z.x y z) (λx, y.x) (λy, z.z)

or

s := (λx, y, z.x y z) (λx, y.x (λy, z.z))

I am guessing it is the 2nd option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is basically unanswerable. It would be easy to define a concrete syntax with either proposed abstract syntax tree, and I don't really think there's such a strong convention one way or the other that you would want to assume one without seeing explicit text in the syntax definition for the document you were reading.

Since this is explicitly tagged Haskell: in this specific case it is simply a parse error, and you are required to add parentheses to disambiguate. Without the first `\x y z -> x y z` function, though, the default would be to parse as `\x y -> (x (\y z -> z))`, and you would need to add parentheses to get the other option of `(\x y -> x) (\y z -> z)`. (The parentheses around `\y z -> z` are not optional.)